# How to download two images asynchronously and only after doing something

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I am using VS2010 on a WPF app. **I cannot use the** `async` **feature**.
Basically I need to load two images, and after images are downloaded a need to print them.

I need to manage the downloading of both images. How to achieve this?

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://abcd.com/logo.png"));
var bitmapB = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://abcd.com/logoB.png"));    

if (!bitmap.IsDownloading)
{
    // print immediately code here
}
else
{
    bitmap.DownloadCompleted += (o, e) =>
    {
        // print when download completed
    };
}    

if (!bitmapB.IsDownloading)
{
    // print immediately
}
else
{
    bitmapB.DownloadCompleted += (o, e) =>
    {
        // print when download completed
    };
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about just downloading them on a background thread, and then when both are downloaded, dispatching some action back on the ui thread for action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following code should do the job for a variable number of images. It downloads all images sequentially in a ThreadPool thread before invoking a `PrintImages` method in the UI thread. Note the after downloading each image is frozen (by `image.Freeze()`) in order to make it cross-thread accessible.

```
private void DownloadAndPrintImagesAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        var images = urls.Select(url => DownloadImage(url));

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => PrintImages(images)));
    });
}

private BitmapImage DownloadImage(string url)
{
    var buffer = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);
    var image = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.StreamSource = stream;
        image.EndInit();
    }

    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}

private void PrintImages(IEnumerable<BitmapImage> images)
{
    // print here
}
```

You might improve this by issuing multiple downloads in parallel, but that would complicate the code. You would have to wait for all asynchronous downloads to be finished before printing.

---

Update: Based on the proposal given by Sheridan, you may modify the `DownloadAndPrintImagesAsync` method like this:

```
private List<BitmapImage> images = new List<BitmapImage>();

private void DownloadAndPrintImagesAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += ImageDownloadCompleted;
        webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
}

private void ImageDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(e.Result))
        {
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.StreamSource = stream;
            image.EndInit();
        }

        images.Add(image);

        if (images.Count == 2) // or whatever
        {
            // print images
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you *really* want is the [`WebClient` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use a number of its methods to download either the image as a file, or as a `byte` collection. The best part is that you can also do this asynchronously, so it will all happen on a background thread automatically.

When using these asynchronous methods, you need to handle the relevant `Download...Completed` event to retrieve the results. From the [`DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

```
public static void DownLoadFileInBackground2 (string address)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    Uri uri = new Uri(address);

    // Specify that the DownloadFileCallback method gets called 
    // when the download completes.
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(
DownloadFileCallback2);
    // Specify a progress notification handler.
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(
DownloadProgressCallback);
    client.DownloadFileAsync (uri, "serverdata.txt");
}
```

Take a look at the [`WebClient.DownloadDataAsync` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddataasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pages on the MSDN website for more information.

Comment: In my specific case I need to call a method print() only when the two images are fully downloaded. For my understanding it seems with your approach I can handle the downloading of 1 picture at a time. How do I check if both images are downloaded?

Comment: In this example, the `DownloadProgressCallback` handler is missing... that is where you retrieve your file when it has been downloaded. If you have two files, then just add an `int` variable to count the number of times that a file has downloaded. If that equals the magic number, then it's time to do whatever you want to next. Also, you can download as many files as you want to *at the same time*... this is asynchronous.